# Vim File Path Search Algorithm

Tags: vim, autocomplete, filepath

**TLDR**. howto change vim path/file name search algorithm from cyclic autocompletion to incremental autocompletion. (like when autocompleting file paths in ubuntu terminal).

When opening a new file for editing in vim, for example using `:vsp` or `:tabe` the algorithm used when pressing the `tab` key to predict the next part of the path/file for the targeted file, has inconvenient behavior that I would like to change.

For example, i have a directory with three files:

```
/one.txt
/onetwo.txt
/onetwothree.txt
```

When attempting to open `onetwothree.txt` from a vim instance opened in the same directory, I would type `:tabe o` then press the `tab` key and vim will autocomplete the file name/path, to `:tabe one.txt`. I must then press `tab` again to change the autocomplete to `:tabe onetwo.txt` and then again a third time to get `:tabe onetwothree.txt`, before pressing `enter` to open the file. (algorithm 1) The `tab` algorithm has the behaviour of cycling through the complete path/file names one by one.

In the ubuntu terminal the search behaviour is much better and works that typing `:tabe o` the pressing `tab` will only partially autocomplete to give you `:tabe one`. Then typing `t` followed by `tab` again will autocomplete from `:tabe onet` to `:tabe onetwo` and then pressing `t` and `tab` again will autocomplete from `:tabe onetwot` to `:tabe onetwothree.txt`. (algorithm 2) The `tab` algorithm has the behaviour of partially completing the path/file name.

With the first algorithm the behaviour of pressing `tab` to cycle through the complete path/file names one by one can be inconvenient when working with lots of files. In the second algorithm shown used by the ubuntu terminal `tab` autocomplete has the behaviour of partially completing the path/file name and allows one to complete the path quickly and accurately.

I realise in this trivial example it takes two more key presses with the second algorithm, but in the non-trivial examples with many files cycling through every option is painful.

How can I change the filepath search algorithm? Is there a setting in the `.vimrc` that specifies it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable `:help 'wildmenu'`:

```
set wildmenu
```

and adjust its behaviour with `:help 'wildmode'`:

```
" just an example
set wildmode=longest,list
```

Comment: You may not have seen it, but this already is stated in the vim-help article I quoted. I extracted the two relevant solution now.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I have added this to my `.vimrc`

Answer (score 0):

from `:h cmdline-completion`

> If you like tcsh's autolist completion, you can use this mapping:
> :cnoremap X  (Where X is the command key to use,  is
> CTRL-L and  is CTRL-D) This will find the longest match and then
> list all matching files.
>
> If you like tcsh's autolist completion, you can use the 'wildmode'
> option to emulate it.  For example, this mimics autolist=ambiguous:
> :set wildmode=longest,list This will find the longest match with the
> first 'wildchar', then list all matching files with the next.

so either map `<c-l><c-d>` in command mode, or adapt `wildmode` to `longest,list`